# Nativescript 7+ incorrect versionName

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Nativescript version: 8.3; vue/ts.

I'm attempting to assign versioning to my Nativescript application, however it doesn't reflect accurately. Everything I've tried results in a versionName of 1.0.0 and versionCode of 1. This behavior occurs whether I am debugging or running a release build.

I've assigned the versionName and versionCode per the [nativescript documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/releasing.html#builds) and [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning). My AndroidManifest.xml ([project_root]/App_Resources/Android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.0.2"
    package="__PACKAGE__">
...
```

Using @nativescript/appversion results in versionName of 1.0.0 and versionCode of 1:

```
let versionName = appversion.getVersionNameSync();
let versionCode = appversion.getVersionCodeSync();
```

I also get the same result when using (which is seemingly deprecated):

```
var packageManager = Application.android.context.getPackageManager();
let versionName = packageManager.getPackageInfo(
  Application.android.context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
let versionCode = packageManager.getPackageInfo(
  Application.android.context.getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
```

As well as:

```
var packageManager = Utils.android.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
let versionName = packageManager.getPackageInfo(
  Utils.android.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
let versionCode = packageManager.getPackageInfo(
  Utils.android.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
```

I've defined nsconfig.json as follows:

```
{
    "appResourcesPath": "App_Resources"
}
```

*I realize this is an optional step, though it is required in my case to work with [nativescript-app-sync](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-app-sync) and a local [nativescript-app-sync-server](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-app-sync-server). Just mentioning for context.*

Comment: What about your app.gradle?

Replace your manifest with this and try.

    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 package="__PACKAGE__"
 android:versionCode="3"
 android:versionName="1.0.2">

Comment: Updating the manifest as you described did not result in any change; but the application ran, which surprised me, as I thought **'__PACKAGE__'** was a [predefined keyword](https://docs.nativescript.org/releasing.html#application-id-and-package-name).
However, updating the app.gradle file directly did work in incrementing the version, so thank you! If you submit this as an answer, I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try updating `versionCode` in app.gradle as well?

Replace your manifest with this and try.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools" 
          package="PACKAGE" 
          android:versionCode="3" 
          android:versionName="1.0.2">
```